# Prevent URL encoding in Response

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, url-encoding

In one of my Resources I'am passing a JSON object to JSP page in Response via Session.

```
@POST
@Path("/updateUser")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response userProfile(
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo, String updateProfileData,
        @Context HttpServletRequest req
) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String session = req.getSession(true).getId();

    JSONObject jsOb = new JSONObject(updateProfileData);
    JSONArray jaArr = jsOb.getJSONArray("profileData");
    JSONObject a;

    StringBuilder sbv = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbk = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";

    try {
        conn = DaoMessenger.PostGresCon().getConnection(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < jaArr.length();) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jaArr.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) { 
                String key = keys.next();
                Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
                sbk.append(prefix);
                sbv.append(prefix);
                prefix = ",";
                sbv.append("'").append(value).append("'");
                sbk.append(key);
            }
            query = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO addresses (" + sbk.toString() + ") values (" + sbv.toString() + ")" );
            System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);

            rs = query.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("RS: " + rs);
            i++;
            System.out.println("rowsUpdated: " + rs);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (rs > 0) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");

        URI uri;
        uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
            .path("../home/index.jsp?page/#/home" )
            .queryParam("obj", URLEncoder.encode(updateProfileData, "UTF-8") )
            .build();
            return Response.seeOther(uri).build();

    } else {
        System.out.println("STUCK SOMEWHERE");
        URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
            .path("/messenger/home/index.jsp?page/#/error;" + req.getSession(true).getId()).build();
        return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
    }

}
```

but I keep facing

> 404 error

as the URL is being encoded and the path too.
So: `?` becomes: `%3F` and `#` becomes: `%23`

Instead of: `http://localhost:8080/messenger/home/index.jsp?page/#/home`

I get: `http://localhost:8080/messenger/home/index.jsp%3Fpage/%23/home`

The second one is not working for me and causes 404 error. I tried couple of solution via google search, but none of them was helpful.

How can I force this to keep the original character for the path after sending the response to the JSP page?

Comment: You can decode it back with URLDecoder.decode before redirecting the url to the browser

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show how you're including the constructed URI in the response to the client?

Comment: @mhasan: I did give it a try but it didn't work

Comment: you are providing a query parameter in the `path()` method

Comment: @Kenster: done. The question have been edited with more code

Comment: @k.vincent the uri syntax is "[scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]" so anything after ? will consider part of query. Just to try out if    URI is the issue, try creating URI like this `URI.create("http://localhost:8080/messenger/home/index.jsp?page/#/home?obj=sdfsd");`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Response creation.

FROM:

```
return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
```

TO:

```
return Response.seeOther(URI.create(uri)).build();
```

Comment: I tried before too. It's not the same type. URI can't be converted to String

Comment: Aren't you using javax.ws.rs.core.Response class? it has public static ResponseBuilder seeOther(URI location) method in it.

Comment: Yes, I'am. import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

Comment: Then you should be able to use my answer

Comment: You may want to check the jaxrs jar version

Comment: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar

Comment: In this you should have the method supporting URI as method parameter to seeOther method